# Is is possible to set multiple passwords in PHP?

Tags: php, passwords

I would like to create a simple login, where the PHP would check if 4 input passwords are correct - kind of like a pin code, but every number would be in a different input form?

Is this possible? I am new to PHP so if you could even recommend a tutorial that can help me with this, that would be great.

Comment: Sure, you can do anything you want with form input data.  What trouble are you having?

Comment: Instead of one password field, make four. Instead of checking one password, check four. Only allow login if all four a correct.

Comment: i think you can find a answer here [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350611/multiple-passwords-login-good-or-bad

Comment: Thanks guys this helps a lot, I'll look into it and @Panique no worries I'll have the fire extinguisher at hand.

Answer (score 5):

Just create one form with multiple input fields.

Comment: yes, 1 form, infinite input fields, so that the user can write the passwords, like: <form><input type='text' name='if1' /><input type='text' name='if2' /><input type='text' name='if3' />...</form>